# Java getMetaData() or getString() does not listen to aliases in SQL query

Tags: java, jdbc

The getMetaData() or getString() function does not listen to the aliases given in my SQL query. The SQL query executes succesfully.

This is a part of my query: `SELECT o.id as o_id, o.package_id as o_package_id, o.client_id as o_client_id, o.reciever_id as o_reciever_id,`

`resultSet.getString(fieldname)` only works with `id`, `package_id`, `client_id`, etc., it does not work with `o.id`, `o.package_id`, `o.client_id`, or the field names I gave them in the query `o_id`, `o_package_id`, `o_client_id`.

This causes a problem, I have a query with multiple JOIN's with double field names.

How can I fetch data by aliases?

Comment: Which database and driver? You can always fetch by positional attribute of course.

Comment: `o.id` can't work as a column name, because the column is still called `id`. Whether or not the JDBC **driver** (not "Java") works with the column alias depends on the _driver_ (and sometimes on the driver *version*)

Comment: @Kayaman InnoDB, JConnector 5.1

Comment: Use [`ResultSetMetadata.getColumnLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel-int-) to check the column "name" returned. It will be the alias or the column name if no alias (AS) is provided as defined by the javadoc. And for information, the documentation state that [`ResultSet.getString(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString-java.lang.String-) will use the label (so the alias if it is provided) to get the correct column. So unless InnoDB didn't implemented the interface fully, this should be ok.

Comment: Please show the code you use. As AxelH indicates, you are probably using `getColumnName` instead of `getColumnLabel`. Values are retrieved from the result set by column label(!), not by column name.

Comment: Thanks, @AxelH. getColumnLabel() does not provide any alias... it returns all the 'default' column names.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I use `getString()` to fetch the data, I don't use `getColumnName()` or `getColumnLabel()`. I already have the column names/labels

Comment: Provide an snippet of you code please. This should not happen (if the JConnector implements the interface of `ResultSet` correctly). Note that `ResultSet` will use the `ResultSetMetaData` to get the index of a column name. So if `ResultSetMetadata.getColumnLabel` doesn't show the correct name, you can't use the alias at all. As said before, you can still use the index instead.

Comment: @axeH I already tried `ResultSetMetadata.getColumnLabel`. See my previous comment. It does not provide any alias. 
I can not use the index, as I said before "This causes a problem, I have a query with multiple JOIN's with double field names." Here a snippet from my code: `DBWrapper DBWrapper = new DBWrapper();
DBWrapper.initialize();
ResultSet resultSet = DBWrapper.executeQuery(query);
System.out.println(resultSet.getString("co_rp_name")));`

Comment: Please post all relevent code **in your question**. Posting it in comments makes it unreadable, also consider that the query as shown doesn't contain a column with the alias `co_rp_name`, so it won't be possible to retrieve a column like that. So far you have failed to post reproducible code, nor have you specified things like the **exact** version of the MySQL Connector/J driver and MySQL you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has something to do with the JConnector.
force the driver url to have useOldAliasMetadataBehavior as true (which has default value of false in v5.1.6)

Should look like this:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true"
```