# SQL Syntax error on production server but working everywhere else

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax-error

In Java (Spring), I have this

```
String query = "delete FROM TASK_SCHEDULER_REPORT t where ((t.DATA_SCHEDULAZIONE is null) and (t.DT_INSERIMENTO < '"+date.toString()+"')) or ((t.DATA_SCHEDULAZIONE is not null) and (t.DATA_SCHEDULAZIONE < '"+date.toString()+"'))";
```

This is a native query and it's actually working on MySql Workbanch, Spring Boot Dashboard and exported as Jar. But deploying on the production server he says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't where ((t.DATA_SCHEDULAZIONE is null) and (t.DT_INSERIMENTO < '2022-04-25')) o' at line 1

What is happening?

Comment: Remove the `t` alias. You don't need it.

Comment: But why is this query working in a query tab and not in java? And why only in production server while working perfectly in local and development server?

Comment: Because obviously the MySQL version is not the same in development and production.

Comment: Yes, I had also thought about this, in fact you are right, but why the same query if I run it on MySQL Workbanch in production works fine while if Java runs it doesn't? Consider that both Workbanch and Java queries work on development server

Comment: Could be related to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351277/java-getmetadata-or-getstring-does-not-listen-to-aliases-in-sql-query